# Finding x in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question is:

> To find the limiting sum of the series $5$+$5x$+$5x^2$+$...$$=$$10$ and then solve the equation to find "$x$", I am aware how to find the limiting sum but I don't have an idea on how to solve for $x$

So far I have done:
($\frac{5x}{5}$) $=$($\frac{5x^2}{5x}$) as per: ($\frac{T2}{T1}$)=($\frac{T3}{T2}$)(aka to find the common ratio $r$)

leading me to:

$25x^2$=$25x^2$

but something tells me I'm on the wrong track, am I?

Comment: Find the geometric series equal to $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see that the sum of this infinite geometric progression has a limit, which implies that its common ratio, $x$, has the following property: $$0\leq\left|x\right|<1$$

We can find the limiting sum: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5(1-x^n)}{1-x}=\color{blue}{\frac{5}{1-x}}\quad( x^n\to0 \text{ as }n\to\infty)$$

And since the limiting sum equals $10$, we have $$\frac{5}{1-x}=10\implies \color{blue}{x=\frac{1}2}$$

---

Note: As John Douma's comment said, you can also divide both sides of the equation by $5$ and get
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots=2$$ and similarly, $$\frac{1}{1-x}=2\implies x=\frac{1}2$$